# Averaging multiple results of a method?

Tags: java, methods, average

So, I have a method that is looping through and returning these numbers automatically :

```
6527.6    6755.6    7009.9    7384.7    7775.9    8170.7    8382.6    8598.8    8867.6    9208.2    9531.8    9821.7   10041.6   10007.2    9847.0   10036.3   10263.5   10449.7   10699.7
```

I would like to average the first number to the second number, the second to the third number, and so on. What ways should I go about doing this? Adding all these doubles to an array? Or is there a way to get a running total in order to do this?

The problem I'm having is that I can only seem to get all or none of these doubles, not specific ones.

So the output would be the results of something like (6527.6+6755.6)/2, (6755.6+7009.9)/2, and so on. Just printing them, nothing else.

Edit : Code from the parser here : http://pastebin.com/V6yvntcP

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "average the first number to the second number" and so on? Where do you get the numbers from (calculated/data structure)?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Also make a new text paragraph, where you point out exactly, what the required output should be.

Comment: Its a lot of code, I've been fiddling with dom parsing. Give me a s ec

Comment: why do you need DOM parsing for this method?

Comment: @LionC I've gotten the data from an XML DOC, and parsed it through DOM.

Comment: why not make a variable outside the loop, and make a calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is known as **moving average**. 
Some formal explanation is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

*[...] simple moving average (SMA) is the unweighted mean of the previous n data [...]*

You want to compute moving average for **n = 2**.

Below is simple code that do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(6527.6, 6755.6, 7009.9, 7384.7, 7775.9, 8170.7);

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        double avg = (list.get(i) + list.get(i - 1)) / 2;
        System.out.println("avg(" + (i - 1) + "," + i + ") = " + avg);
    }
}
```

And second approach without List or array:

```
Double prev = null;

// inside loop:

double curr = getMethodResult(...);

if (prev != null) {
    double avg = (curr + prev) / 2;
}

prev = curr;

// end of loop
```

Comment: The problem with the second solution is that the method I am getting data from is continuously spitting out numbers, so first it spits out 6527.6, then the next, and then the next. Its kind of like its replacing the variable over and over again. 

I'll update my main post with the code of the parser method that is spitting the numbers out

Answer (score 0):

Create and array of double and just do some traversing and swapping and its done. Check it out:

```
  double[] array = { 6527.6, 6755.6, 7009.9, 7384.7, 7775.9, 8170.7 };
        double avg = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        double temp = 6527.6;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            sum = temp + array[i + 1];
            avg = sum / 2;
            System.out.println("(" + temp + "+" + array[i + 1] + ")/2" + "= "
                    + avg);
            temp = avg;

        }
```